# Find the differences between 2 array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have 2 arrays

I'm trying to find the difference between them.

I want to know what is the value that in array2 that array1 don't have, and vice of versa.

I've tried

```
$array_intersect = array_intersect(array_values($collections_code),array_values($languages_code));
$array_diff = array_diff(array_values($collections_code),array_values($languages_code));

dd(
    'array_intersect : --------- ',$array_intersect,
    'array_diff : --------- ',$array_diff
);
```

---

## 2 Arrays

**array1**

```
array:312 [▼
  0 => "h"
  1 => "p1"
  2 => "p2"
  3 => "modify"
  4 => "more_settings"
  5 => "on"
  6 => "off"
  7 => "day_0"
  8 => "day_1"
  9 => "day_2"
  10 => "day_3"
  11 => "day_4"
  12 => "day_5"
  13 => "day_6"
  14 => "minutes"
  15 => "hours"
  16 => "day"
  17 => "days"
  18 => "wifi_err"
  19 => "wifi_private_1"
  20 => "wifi_private_2"
  21 => "wifi_private_3"
  22 => "wifi_private_4"
  23 => "wifi_private_5"
  24 => "wifi_private_6"
  25 => "wifi_private_7"
  26 => "wifi_guest_1"
  27 => "wifi_guest_2"
  28 => "wifi_guest_3"
  29 => "wifi_guest_4"
  30 => "wifi_guest_5"
  31 => "wifi_guest_6"
  32 => "wifi_guest_7"
  33 => "wifi_guest_8"
  34 => "wifi_guest_9"
  35 => "wifi_info_bar"
  36 => "wifi_info_1"
  37 => "wifi_info_2"
  38 => "wifi_info_3"
  39 => "wifi_info_6"
  40 => "wifi_status"
  41 => "firewall_11"
  42 => "wifi_settings_h"
  43 => "wifi_guest_bar"
  44 => "private_h"
  45 => "private_p"
  46 => "private_bar"
  47 => "private_3_tip"
  48 => "private_4"
  49 => "private_4_tip"
  50 => "private_6"
  51 => "private_7"
  52 => "guest_bar"
  53 => "guest_2"
  54 => "guest_3"
  55 => "guest_4"
  56 => "guest_5"
  57 => "guest_6"
  58 => "guest_12"
  59 => "guest_13"
  60 => "guest_14"
  61 => "login_1_1"
  62 => "login_1_2"
  63 => "login_1_3"
  64 => "login_1_4"
  65 => "login_2"
  66 => "login_2_1"
  67 => "login_2_2"
  68 => "login_2_3"
  69 => "login_2_4"
  70 => "login_2_5"
  71 => "login_4"
  72 => "firewall_12"
  73 => "firewall_13"
  74 => "private_1"
  75 => "guest_1"
  76 => "private_3"
  77 => "guest_7"
  78 => "wifi_private_2"
  79 => "guest_9"
  80 => "guest_10"
  81 => "guest_11"
  82 => "login_1"
  83 => "guest_8"
  84 => "private_5_tip"
  85 => "private_2"
  86 => "login_bar"
  87 => "login_2_desc"
  88 => "wifi_guest_3"
  89 => "login_3"
  90 => "wifi_guest_5"
  91 => "wifi_guest_6"
  92 => "wifi_guest_7"
  93 => "wifi_guest_8"
  94 => "login_3_desc"
  95 => "promotion_manager_bar"
  96 => "promotion_heading"
  97 => "promotion"
  98 => "current_promotions"
  99 => "promotion_name"
  100 => "promotion_status"
  101 => "promotion_actions"
  102 => "promotion_preview"
  103 => "promotion_add"
  104 => "bandwidth_3"
  105 => "promotion_edit"
  106 => "wifi_guest_bar"
  107 => "promotion_max_count"
  108 => "private_h"
  109 => "promotion_activate"
  110 => "promotion_heading_text"
  111 => "promotion_media_type"
  112 => "promotion_no_media"
  113 => "promotion_choose_file"
  114 => "promotion_image_upload"
  115 => "promotion_image_file"
  116 => "promotion_image_link"
  117 => "promotion_video_link"
  118 => "promotion_video_upload"
  119 => "promotion_choose_mp4"
  120 => "promotion_video_file"
  121 => "promotion_body_text"
  122 => "promotion_footer_text"
  123 => "promotion_save"
  124 => "bandwidth_bar"
  125 => "bandwidth_4"
  126 => "lan_bar"
  127 => "lan_1"
  128 => "lan_2"
  129 => "lan_3"
  130 => "lan_4"
  131 => "lan_5"
  132 => "lan_6"
  133 => "lan_7"
  134 => "lan_8"
  135 => "lan_9"
  136 => "lan_10"
  137 => "firewall_bar"
  138 => "firewall_1"
  139 => "firewall_2"
  140 => "firewall_3"
  141 => "firewall_4"
  142 => "firewall_5"
  143 => "firewall_6"
  144 => "firewall_7"
  145 => "firewall_8"
  146 => "firewall_9a"
  147 => "firewall_9b"
  148 => "firewall_10a"
  149 => "firewall_10b"
  150 => "login_1_5"
  151 => "bandwidth_2"
  152 => "bandwidth_3"
  153 => "firewall_14"
  154 => "login_2_1"
  155 => "firewall_15"
  156 => "login_2_3"
  157 => "firewall_16"
  158 => "cloud_security_bar"
  159 => "login_3"
  160 => "cloud_security_1"
  161 => "cloud_security_2"
  162 => "cloud_security_3"
  163 => "cloud_security_4"
  164 => "cloud_security_5"
  165 => "device_bar"
  166 => "device_uplink"
  167 => "note"
  168 => "device_downlink"
  169 => "device_action"
  170 => "device_block"
  171 => "stats_title"
  172 => "stats_device_name"
  173 => "stats_private_label"
  174 => "homegateway"
  175 => "stats_guest_label"
  176 => "stats_no_private"
  177 => "stats_no_guest"
  178 => "stats_visitor_1"
  179 => "stats_visitor_2"
  180 => "stats_visitor_3"
  181 => "stats_visitor_4"
  182 => "stats_visitor_5"
  183 => "stats_visitor_6"
  184 => "stats_visitor_7"
  185 => "stats_visitor_8"
  186 => "stats_visitor_9"
  187 => "stats_visitor_10"
  188 => "nav_dashboard"
  189 => "nav_private_settings"
  190 => "nav_guest_settings"
  191 => "nav_stats"
  192 => "private_5"
  193 => "wifi_private_bar"
  194 => "wifi_settings_p"
  195 => "cp_male"
  196 => "bandwidth_1"
  197 => "cp_err_1"
  198 => "login_1_desc"
  199 => "private_2_tip"
  200 => "stats_desc"
  201 => "stats_devices_title"
  202 => "stats_ip_address"
  203 => "login_4_desc"
  204 => "stats_network_title"
  205 => "stats_visitor_title"
  206 => "email"
  207 => "password"
  208 => "disclaimer"
  209 => "add_entry"
  210 => "logout"
  211 => "go"
  212 => "please_wait"
  213 => "uplink"
  214 => "downlink"
  215 => "help"
  216 => "both"
  217 => "and"
  218 => "auto"
  219 => "manage"
  220 => "private"
  221 => "guest"
  222 => "browser_analytics"
  223 => "passerby"
  224 => "visitor"
  225 => "visitor_chart_xaxisname"
  226 => "visitor_chart_yaxisname"
  227 => "visitor_chart_title"
  228 => "save"
  229 => "nav_1"
  230 => "select_ap"
  231 => "select_language"
  232 => "wifi_private_bar"
  233 => "wifi_private_8"
  234 => "ap"
  235 => "unmanaged_ap"
  236 => "lan_9"
  237 => "managed_ap"
  238 => "limit"
  239 => "c_managed_ap"
  240 => "login_4_h"
  241 => "login_1_5"
  242 => "login_1_6"
  243 => "cp_option_1"
  244 => "cp_option_2"
  245 => "cp_option_3"
  246 => "firewall_bar"
  247 => "cp_option_4"
  248 => "cp_logo"
  249 => "cp_main_logo"
  250 => "cp_upload_logo"
  251 => "cp_choose_a_file"
  252 => "cp_file"
  253 => "cp_color"
  254 => "cp_background"
  255 => "cp_subtitle_text"
  256 => "cp_text_content"
  257 => "cp_title"
  258 => "cp_firstname"
  259 => "cp_lastname"
  260 => "cp_email_addess"
  261 => "cp_gender"
  262 => "cp_male"
  263 => "cp_female"
  264 => "cp_err_1"
  265 => "cloud_security_bar"
  266 => "cp_err_2"
  267 => "promotion_saving_promotion"
  268 => "promotion_continue_browsing"
  269 => "lan_11"
  270 => "lan_12"
  271 => "lan_error"
  272 => "lan_error2"
  273 => "lan_error3"
  274 => "lan_error4"
  275 => "lan_error5"
  276 => "device_bandwidth"
  277 => "device_access"
  278 => "device_none"
  279 => "device_allow"
  280 => "device_scheldule"
  281 => "device_last_active"
  282 => "device_url"
  283 => "device_header"
  284 => "stats_title"
  285 => "stats_visitor_11"
  286 => "stats_visitor_12"
  287 => "stats_devices_title"
  288 => "stats_device_name"
  289 => "stats_ip_address"
  290 => "stats_private_label"
  291 => "stats_visitor_13"
  292 => "inactive"
  293 => "stats_no_guest"
  294 => "active"
  295 => "offline"
  296 => "stats_visitor_2"
  297 => "all_address"
  298 => "stats_visitor_4"
  299 => "stats_visitor_5"
  300 => "stats_visitor_6"
  301 => "wifi_h"
  302 => "stats_visitor_8"
  303 => "stats_visitor_9"
  304 => "stats_visitor_10"
  305 => "stats_visitor_11"
  306 => "stats_visitor_12"
  307 => "stats_visitor_13"
  308 => "nav_dashboard"
  309 => "nav_private_settings"
  310 => "nav_guest_settings"
  311 => "wifi_p1"
]
```

**array2**

```
array:313 [▼
  0 => "h"
  1 => "p1"
  2 => "p2"
  3 => "modify"
  4 => "more_settings"
  5 => "on"
  6 => "off"
  7 => "email"
  8 => "password"
  9 => "disclaimer"
  10 => "add_entry"
  11 => "logout"
  12 => "go"
  13 => "please_wait"
  14 => "uplink"
  15 => "downlink"
  16 => "help"
  17 => "both"
  18 => "and"
  19 => "auto"
  20 => "manage"
  21 => "private"
  22 => "guest"
  23 => "browser_analytics"
  24 => "passerby"
  25 => "visitor"
  26 => "visitor_chart_xaxisname"
  27 => "visitor_chart_yaxisname"
  28 => "visitor_chart_title"
  29 => "save"
  30 => "inactive"
  31 => "active"
  32 => "offline"
  33 => "search"
  34 => "copy"
  35 => "print"
  36 => "nav_1"
  37 => "select_ap"
  38 => "select_language"
  39 => "day_0"
  40 => "day_1"
  41 => "day_2"
  42 => "day_3"
  43 => "day_4"
  44 => "day_5"
  45 => "day_6"
  46 => "second"
  47 => "minute"
  48 => "hour"
  49 => "day"
  50 => "week"
  51 => "month"
  52 => "year"
  53 => "seconds"
  54 => "minutes"
  55 => "hours"
  56 => "days"
  57 => "weeks"
  58 => "months"
  59 => "years"
  60 => "second_ago"
  61 => "minute_ago"
  62 => "hour_ago"
  63 => "day_ago"
  64 => "week_ago"
  65 => "month_ago"
  66 => "year_ago"
  67 => "seconds_ago"
  68 => "minutes_ago"
  69 => "hours_ago"
  70 => "days_ago"
  71 => "weeks_ago"
  72 => "months_ago"
  73 => "years_ago"
  74 => "wifi_h"
  75 => "wifi_p1"
  76 => "wifi_err"
  77 => "wifi_private_bar"
  78 => "wifi_private_1"
  79 => "wifi_private_2"
  80 => "wifi_private_3"
  81 => "wifi_private_4"
  82 => "wifi_private_5"
  83 => "wifi_private_6"
  84 => "wifi_private_7"
  85 => "wifi_private_8"
  86 => "wifi_guest_bar"
  87 => "wifi_guest_1"
  88 => "wifi_guest_2"
  89 => "wifi_guest_3"
  90 => "wifi_guest_4"
  91 => "wifi_guest_5"
  92 => "wifi_guest_6"
  93 => "wifi_guest_7"
  94 => "wifi_guest_8"
  95 => "wifi_guest_9"
  96 => "wifi_info_bar"
  97 => "wifi_info_1"
  98 => "wifi_info_2"
  99 => "wifi_info_3"
  100 => "wifi_info_6"
  101 => "wifi_status"
  102 => "bandwidth_bar"
  103 => "bandwidth_1"
  104 => "bandwidth_2"
  105 => "bandwidth_3"
  106 => "bandwidth_4"
  107 => "wifi_settings_h"
  108 => "wifi_settings_p"
  109 => "private_h"
  110 => "private_p"
  111 => "private_bar"
  112 => "private_1"
  113 => "private_2"
  114 => "private_2_tip"
  115 => "private_3"
  116 => "private_3_tip"
  117 => "private_4"
  118 => "private_4_tip"
  119 => "private_5"
  120 => "private_5_tip"
  121 => "private_6"
  122 => "private_7"
  123 => "homegateway"
  124 => "ap"
  125 => "unmanaged_ap"
  126 => "managed_ap"
  127 => "limit"
  128 => "c_managed_ap"
  129 => "guest_bar"
  130 => "guest_1"
  131 => "guest_2"
  132 => "guest_3"
  133 => "guest_4"
  134 => "guest_5"
  135 => "guest_6"
  136 => "guest_7"
  137 => "guest_8"
  138 => "guest_9"
  139 => "guest_10"
  140 => "guest_11"
  141 => "guest_12"
  142 => "guest_13"
  143 => "guest_14"
  144 => "login_bar"
  145 => "login_1"
  146 => "login_1_desc"
  147 => "login_1_1"
  148 => "login_1_2"
  149 => "login_1_3"
  150 => "login_1_4"
  151 => "login_1_5"
  152 => "login_1_6"
  153 => "login_2"
  154 => "login_2_desc"
  155 => "login_2_1"
  156 => "login_2_2"
  157 => "login_2_3"
  158 => "login_2_4"
  159 => "login_2_5"
  160 => "login_3"
  161 => "login_3_desc"
  162 => "activate_fb"
  163 => "config_status"
  164 => "facebook_pg"
  165 => "configure"
  166 => "refresh_status"
  167 => "deactivate"
  168 => "note"
  169 => "redirect_fb_pg"
  170 => "save_set"
  171 => "hit"
  172 => "update_status"
  173 => "close"
  174 => "got_it"
  175 => "login_4"
  176 => "login_4_desc"
  177 => "login_4_h"
  178 => "cp_option_1"
  179 => "cp_option_2"
  180 => "cp_option_3"
  181 => "cp_option_4"
  182 => "cp_logo"
  183 => "cp_main_logo"
  184 => "cp_upload_logo"
  185 => "cp_choose_a_file"
  186 => "cp_file"
  187 => "cp_color"
  188 => "cp_background"
  189 => "cp_subtitle_text"
  190 => "cp_text_content"
  191 => "cp_title"
  192 => "cp_firstname"
  193 => "cp_lastname"
  194 => "cp_email_addess"
  195 => "cp_gender"
  196 => "cp_male"
  197 => "cp_female"
  198 => "cp_err_1"
  199 => "cp_err_2"
  200 => "promotion_manager_bar"
  201 => "promotion_heading"
  202 => "promotion"
  203 => "current_promotions"
  204 => "promotion_name"
  205 => "promotion_status"
  206 => "promotion_actions"
  207 => "promotion_preview"
  208 => "promotion_add"
  209 => "promotion_edit"
  210 => "promotion_max_count"
  211 => "promotion_activate"
  212 => "promotion_heading_text"
  213 => "promotion_media_type"
  214 => "promotion_no_media"
  215 => "promotion_choose_file"
  216 => "promotion_image_upload"
  217 => "promotion_image_file"
  218 => "promotion_image_link"
  219 => "promotion_video_link"
  220 => "promotion_video_upload"
  221 => "promotion_choose_mp4"
  222 => "promotion_video_file"
  223 => "promotion_body_text"
  224 => "promotion_footer_text"
  225 => "promotion_save"
  226 => "promotion_saving_promotion"
  227 => "promotion_continue_browsing"
  228 => "lan_bar"
  229 => "lan_1"
  230 => "lan_2"
  231 => "lan_3"
  232 => "lan_4"
  233 => "lan_5"
  234 => "lan_6"
  235 => "lan_7"
  236 => "lan_8"
  237 => "lan_9"
  238 => "lan_10"
  239 => "lan_11"
  240 => "lan_12"
  241 => "lan_error"
  242 => "lan_error2"
  243 => "lan_error3"
  244 => "lan_error4"
  245 => "lan_error5"
  246 => "all_address"
  247 => "firewall_bar"
  248 => "firewall_1"
  249 => "firewall_2"
  250 => "firewall_3"
  251 => "firewall_4"
  252 => "firewall_5"
  253 => "firewall_6"
  254 => "firewall_7"
  255 => "firewall_8"
  256 => "firewall_9a"
  257 => "firewall_9b"
  258 => "firewall_10a"
  259 => "firewall_10b"
  260 => "firewall_11"
  261 => "firewall_12"
  262 => "firewall_13"
  263 => "firewall_14"
  264 => "firewall_15"
  265 => "firewall_16"
  266 => "cloud_security_bar"
  267 => "cloud_security_header"
  268 => "cloud_security_none"
  269 => "cloud_security_restricted"
  270 => "cloud_security_medium"
  271 => "cloud_security_low"
  272 => "device_bar"
  273 => "device_uplink"
  274 => "device_downlink"
  275 => "device_action"
  276 => "device_block"
  277 => "device_bandwidth"
  278 => "device_access"
  279 => "device_none"
  280 => "device_allow"
  281 => "device_scheldule"
  282 => "device_last_active"
  283 => "device_url"
  284 => "device_header"
  285 => "stats_title"
  286 => "stats_desc"
  287 => "stats_network_title"
  288 => "stats_devices_title"
  289 => "stats_device_name"
  290 => "stats_ip_address"
  291 => "stats_private_label"
  292 => "stats_guest_label"
  293 => "stats_no_private"
  294 => "stats_no_guest"
  295 => "stats_visitor_title"
  296 => "stats_visitor_1"
  297 => "stats_visitor_2"
  298 => "stats_visitor_3"
  299 => "stats_visitor_4"
  300 => "stats_visitor_5"
  301 => "stats_visitor_6"
  302 => "stats_visitor_7"
  303 => "stats_visitor_8"
  304 => "stats_visitor_9"
  305 => "stats_visitor_10"
  306 => "stats_visitor_11"
  307 => "stats_visitor_12"
  308 => "stats_visitor_13"
  309 => "nav_dashboard"
  310 => "nav_private_settings"
  311 => "nav_guest_settings"
  312 => "nav_stats"
]
```

---

## Result

**"array_intersect : --------- "**

```
array:307 [▼
  0 => "h"
  1 => "p1"
  2 => "p2"
  3 => "modify"
  4 => "more_settings"
  5 => "on"
  6 => "off"
  7 => "day_0"
  8 => "day_1"
  9 => "day_2"
  10 => "day_3"
  11 => "day_4"
  12 => "day_5"
  13 => "day_6"
  14 => "minutes"
  15 => "hours"
  16 => "day"
  17 => "days"
  18 => "wifi_err"
  19 => "wifi_private_1"
  20 => "wifi_private_2"
  21 => "wifi_private_3"
  22 => "wifi_private_4"
  23 => "wifi_private_5"
  24 => "wifi_private_6"
  25 => "wifi_private_7"
  26 => "wifi_guest_1"
  27 => "wifi_guest_2"
  28 => "wifi_guest_3"
  29 => "wifi_guest_4"
  30 => "wifi_guest_5"
  31 => "wifi_guest_6"
  32 => "wifi_guest_7"
  33 => "wifi_guest_8"
  34 => "wifi_guest_9"
  35 => "wifi_info_bar"
  36 => "wifi_info_1"
  37 => "wifi_info_2"
  38 => "wifi_info_3"
  39 => "wifi_info_6"
  40 => "wifi_status"
  41 => "firewall_11"
  42 => "wifi_settings_h"
  43 => "wifi_guest_bar"
  44 => "private_h"
  45 => "private_p"
  46 => "private_bar"
  47 => "private_3_tip"
  48 => "private_4"
  49 => "private_4_tip"
  50 => "private_6"
  51 => "private_7"
  52 => "guest_bar"
  53 => "guest_2"
  54 => "guest_3"
  55 => "guest_4"
  56 => "guest_5"
  57 => "guest_6"
  58 => "guest_12"
  59 => "guest_13"
  60 => "guest_14"
  61 => "login_1_1"
  62 => "login_1_2"
  63 => "login_1_3"
  64 => "login_1_4"
  65 => "login_2"
  66 => "login_2_1"
  67 => "login_2_2"
  68 => "login_2_3"
  69 => "login_2_4"
  70 => "login_2_5"
  71 => "login_4"
  72 => "firewall_12"
  73 => "firewall_13"
  74 => "private_1"
  75 => "guest_1"
  76 => "private_3"
  77 => "guest_7"
  78 => "wifi_private_2"
  79 => "guest_9"
  80 => "guest_10"
  81 => "guest_11"
  82 => "login_1"
  83 => "guest_8"
  84 => "private_5_tip"
  85 => "private_2"
  86 => "login_bar"
  87 => "login_2_desc"
  88 => "wifi_guest_3"
  89 => "login_3"
  90 => "wifi_guest_5"
  91 => "wifi_guest_6"
  92 => "wifi_guest_7"
  93 => "wifi_guest_8"
  94 => "login_3_desc"
  95 => "promotion_manager_bar"
  96 => "promotion_heading"
  97 => "promotion"
  98 => "current_promotions"
  99 => "promotion_name"
  100 => "promotion_status"
  101 => "promotion_actions"
  102 => "promotion_preview"
  103 => "promotion_add"
  104 => "bandwidth_3"
  105 => "promotion_edit"
  106 => "wifi_guest_bar"
  107 => "promotion_max_count"
  108 => "private_h"
  109 => "promotion_activate"
  110 => "promotion_heading_text"
  111 => "promotion_media_type"
  112 => "promotion_no_media"
  113 => "promotion_choose_file"
  114 => "promotion_image_upload"
  115 => "promotion_image_file"
  116 => "promotion_image_link"
  117 => "promotion_video_link"
  118 => "promotion_video_upload"
  119 => "promotion_choose_mp4"
  120 => "promotion_video_file"
  121 => "promotion_body_text"
  122 => "promotion_footer_text"
  123 => "promotion_save"
  124 => "bandwidth_bar"
  125 => "bandwidth_4"
  126 => "lan_bar"
  127 => "lan_1"
  128 => "lan_2"
  129 => "lan_3"
  130 => "lan_4"
  131 => "lan_5"
  132 => "lan_6"
  133 => "lan_7"
  134 => "lan_8"
  135 => "lan_9"
  136 => "lan_10"
  137 => "firewall_bar"
  138 => "firewall_1"
  139 => "firewall_2"
  140 => "firewall_3"
  141 => "firewall_4"
  142 => "firewall_5"
  143 => "firewall_6"
  144 => "firewall_7"
  145 => "firewall_8"
  146 => "firewall_9a"
  147 => "firewall_9b"
  148 => "firewall_10a"
  149 => "firewall_10b"
  150 => "login_1_5"
  151 => "bandwidth_2"
  152 => "bandwidth_3"
  153 => "firewall_14"
  154 => "login_2_1"
  155 => "firewall_15"
  156 => "login_2_3"
  157 => "firewall_16"
  158 => "cloud_security_bar"
  159 => "login_3"
  165 => "device_bar"
  166 => "device_uplink"
  167 => "note"
  168 => "device_downlink"
  169 => "device_action"
  170 => "device_block"
  171 => "stats_title"
  172 => "stats_device_name"
  173 => "stats_private_label"
  174 => "homegateway"
  175 => "stats_guest_label"
  176 => "stats_no_private"
  177 => "stats_no_guest"
  178 => "stats_visitor_1"
  179 => "stats_visitor_2"
  180 => "stats_visitor_3"
  181 => "stats_visitor_4"
  182 => "stats_visitor_5"
  183 => "stats_visitor_6"
  184 => "stats_visitor_7"
  185 => "stats_visitor_8"
  186 => "stats_visitor_9"
  187 => "stats_visitor_10"
  188 => "nav_dashboard"
  189 => "nav_private_settings"
  190 => "nav_guest_settings"
  191 => "nav_stats"
  192 => "private_5"
  193 => "wifi_private_bar"
  194 => "wifi_settings_p"
  195 => "cp_male"
  196 => "bandwidth_1"
  197 => "cp_err_1"
  198 => "login_1_desc"
  199 => "private_2_tip"
  200 => "stats_desc"
  201 => "stats_devices_title"
  202 => "stats_ip_address"
  203 => "login_4_desc"
  204 => "stats_network_title"
  205 => "stats_visitor_title"
  206 => "email"
  207 => "password"
  208 => "disclaimer"
  209 => "add_entry"
  210 => "logout"
  211 => "go"
  212 => "please_wait"
  213 => "uplink"
  214 => "downlink"
  215 => "help"
  216 => "both"
  217 => "and"
  218 => "auto"
  219 => "manage"
  220 => "private"
  221 => "guest"
  222 => "browser_analytics"
  223 => "passerby"
  224 => "visitor"
  225 => "visitor_chart_xaxisname"
  226 => "visitor_chart_yaxisname"
  227 => "visitor_chart_title"
  228 => "save"
  229 => "nav_1"
  230 => "select_ap"
  231 => "select_language"
  232 => "wifi_private_bar"
  233 => "wifi_private_8"
  234 => "ap"
  235 => "unmanaged_ap"
  236 => "lan_9"
  237 => "managed_ap"
  238 => "limit"
  239 => "c_managed_ap"
  240 => "login_4_h"
  241 => "login_1_5"
  242 => "login_1_6"
  243 => "cp_option_1"
  244 => "cp_option_2"
  245 => "cp_option_3"
  246 => "firewall_bar"
  247 => "cp_option_4"
  248 => "cp_logo"
  249 => "cp_main_logo"
  250 => "cp_upload_logo"
  251 => "cp_choose_a_file"
  252 => "cp_file"
  253 => "cp_color"
  254 => "cp_background"
  255 => "cp_subtitle_text"
  256 => "cp_text_content"
  257 => "cp_title"
  258 => "cp_firstname"
  259 => "cp_lastname"
  260 => "cp_email_addess"
  261 => "cp_gender"
  262 => "cp_male"
  263 => "cp_female"
  264 => "cp_err_1"
  265 => "cloud_security_bar"
  266 => "cp_err_2"
  267 => "promotion_saving_promotion"
  268 => "promotion_continue_browsing"
  269 => "lan_11"
  270 => "lan_12"
  271 => "lan_error"
  272 => "lan_error2"
  273 => "lan_error3"
  274 => "lan_error4"
  275 => "lan_error5"
  276 => "device_bandwidth"
  277 => "device_access"
  278 => "device_none"
  279 => "device_allow"
  280 => "device_scheldule"
  281 => "device_last_active"
  282 => "device_url"
  283 => "device_header"
  284 => "stats_title"
  285 => "stats_visitor_11"
  286 => "stats_visitor_12"
  287 => "stats_devices_title"
  288 => "stats_device_name"
  289 => "stats_ip_address"
  290 => "stats_private_label"
  291 => "stats_visitor_13"
  292 => "inactive"
  293 => "stats_no_guest"
  294 => "active"
  295 => "offline"
  296 => "stats_visitor_2"
  297 => "all_address"
  298 => "stats_visitor_4"
  299 => "stats_visitor_5"
  300 => "stats_visitor_6"
  301 => "wifi_h"
  302 => "stats_visitor_8"
  303 => "stats_visitor_9"
  304 => "stats_visitor_10"
  305 => "stats_visitor_11"
  306 => "stats_visitor_12"
  307 => "stats_visitor_13"
  308 => "nav_dashboard"
  309 => "nav_private_settings"
  310 => "nav_guest_settings"
  311 => "wifi_p1"
]
```

**"array_diff : --------- "**

```
array:5 [▼
  160 => "cloud_security_1"
  161 => "cloud_security_2"
  162 => "cloud_security_3"
  163 => "cloud_security_4"
  164 => "cloud_security_5"
]
```

How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: Might be easier if you point out where your expectations are not being met

Comment: `array_diff` only show 5 in my dd result. BUT, I can easily spots more than by just looking at both arrays.

Comment: I am quickly spots 14 of these that I know it is exist in array2, but never exist in array1. See this image here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0bpym5e0rle3vk/%202018-02-07%20at%207.15.02%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Maybe I need to run it twice ? `array1diffarray2` + `array2diffarray1` ? ... maybe ?

Comment: Maybe you do, maybe you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) to do this, specifically the [`diff`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-diff) method:

> This method will return the values in the original collection that are not present in the given collection:

You can find items that exist in the first array that do not exist in the second like this:

```
$diff = collect($array1)->diff($array2);
```

That will return an array of 44 missing items — based on the values you provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 $result = array_merge(array_diff(array_values($collections_code),array_values($languages_code)),array_diff(array_values($languages_code),array_values($collections_code)));

 print_r($result);
```